# Initializing global arrays after declaration in C

Tags: arrays, c, global

I need a global array whose size depends on the user. The problem is I don't know how to declare an array globally but initialize it later after getting a user input to know the size. I am not even sure if it is possible since the storage for the array is assigned after the program starts running.
So my question is, how do I initialize a global array after declaration to an array of size t?

```
// What I want to achieve 
...
struct some_name* sn;
...

int main(){
...
   sn = some_name[t]; // Where t is unkown before running the code
...
}
```

Comment: You'll need to allocate it with e.g. `malloc()`.

Comment: @Randaniel I do not see any array declaration.

Comment: `sn = malloc(t * sizeof *sn);`

Answer (score 5):

You can dynamically allocate your array at run-time like so:

```
struct some_name* sn;
....
sn = malloc(t * sizeof(struct some_name));
```

This has the downside that you are repeating the type name twice, and if the type of `sn` ever changed, you'd have to remember to change the `malloc()` too.

An equivalent alternative that avoids this problem is:

```
sn = malloc(t * sizeof *sn);
```

Memory allocated by `malloc()` is uninitialised, and may contain anything. If you want zero-filled memory, you can use:

```
sn = calloc(t, sizeof *sn);
```

Don't forget to free your memory when you are finished with it:

```
free(sn);
```

Also, don't forget that both `malloc()` and `calloc()` can return `NULL` if they fail to allocate the memory you requested. You should always check for that, and handle the error appropriately.

Edit: Note that `struct some_name* sn;` defines a pointer, not an array. After you have allocated the required memory for it and set `sn` to that value, it can be treated like an array, e.g. you can access its elements using the same `[]` notation:

```
sn[0].foo = 12;
```

Answer (score 4):

> how do I initialize a global array after decleration to an array of size t?

In C, *initialization* has a specific meaning and cannot occur after definition.  *Assignment* can happen later.

Once an *array* is defined, its size never changes so code cannot have an array of a size and later change to another.

Instead, code can allocate memory later and assign it to a pointer.

```
#iinclude <stdlib.h>

struct some_name* sn = NULL;
size_t sn_size = 0;

int main() {
  sn_size = foo(); // some user input
  sn = malloc(sizeof sn[0] * sn_size);
  if (sn == NULL && sn_size > 0) {
    Handle_error();
  }

  // Assign
  for (size_t i = 0; i < sn_size; i++) {
    sn[i] = ...; // OP's assignment code.
  }

  ...

  free(sn);
}
```

Allocation size can change.  Example: `realloc()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct some_name* sn;

int main()
{
    sn = malloc(t*sizeof(some_name)); // stores garbage values by default
    // sn = calloc(t, sizeof(some_name)); // stores zero values by default
    free(sn); // free the memory space
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to remove the line. You're right because t is used to initialize the memory space.